# Creating a new *Dialer with gomail.v2

Tags: email, go, package

I'm using [gomail.v2](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/gomail.v2) to send emails, and my code works fine. After composing a message `msg` I can just run

```
import ("gopkg.in/gomail.v2")

  ...
  d := gomail.NewDialer("smtp.example.com", 25, "username", "password")
  return d.DialAndSend(msg)
}
```

Of course I'd like to generalize this past a particular username and password and separate it into its own function, so I stubbed it out:

```
import ("gopkg.in/gomail.v2")

  ...
  d := MyDialer()
  return d.DialAndSend(msg)
}

func MyDialer() *Dialer {
  return gomail.NewDialer("smtp.example.com", 25, "username", "password")
}
```

But go croaks, complaining that it doesn't know about Dialer.

> .\email.go:42: undefined: Dialer

Why is this? I'm using the same return type as `NewDialer`, which doesn't cause any problems.

```
func NewDialer(host string, port int, username, password string) *Dialer
```

What am I missing? I ran

> go get -u gopkg.in/gomail.v2

to make sure I wasn't somehow running an out of date version of the package, but no luck there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`*Dialer` and `*gomail.Dialer` are 2 different types. The specific error is because you don't have a `Dialer` type defined in your package, but you need to match the types in the signature, not just the name. Since `gomail.NewDialer` returns a `*gomail.Dialer`, use:

```
func MyDialer() *gomail.Dialer {
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you! As a go beginner (this is really my first project), how could I have discovered this on my own? I don't want to have to ask a bunch of dumb questions on SO. :)

Comment: @Charles: you'll get the hang of interpreting the compiler errors pretty quick, and they are usually quite good (though the usual missing brace can still throw things pretty far off). `undefined: Dialer` means there's no `Dialer` in your package, and since it's not something you intended to declare yourself, it must be the wrong type. Since everything from an imported package must always be prefixed with the package identifier, a `Dialer` from `gomail` must be referenced as `gomail.Dialer`.